# Unable to create launchtemplate using awscli

Tags: amazon-web-services

Running into the following error:
`Invalid type for parameter LaunchTemplateData.CreditSpecification, value: CpuCredits:unlimited, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>`

Using the following command:

`aws ec2 create-launch-template --launch-template-name MyLaunchTemplate --version-description FirstVersion --launch-template-data ImageId=ami-8c1
be5f6,InstanceType=t2.medium,CreditSpecification=CpuCredits:unlimited`

awscli version: `aws-cli/1.14.12`

According to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html...

Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `launch-template-data` to a JSON. The problem is that `CreditSpecification` is a JSON and `CpuCredits:unlimited` is not the right way to do it. Refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html#create-launch-template) amazon documentation for an example.

Comment: I facepalmed when I just saw your answer. I tried to use a JSON string inside a regular string.........stupid me. Thanks man!

Comment: So I changed it to a JSON but I dont see any mention of the credits in the object it creates:` {
    "LaunchTemplates": [
        {
            "LatestVersionNumber": 1,
            "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-0dcbd37bedf2e9651",
            "LaunchTemplateName": "MyLaunchTemplate",
            "DefaultVersionNumber": 1,
            "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:iam::arn:user/user",
            "CreateTime": "2017-12-19T16:51:59.000Z"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Used this as a command: `aws ec2 create-launch-template --launch-template-name MyLaunchTemplate --version-description FirstVersion --launch-template-data '{"ImageId": "ami-8c1be5f6", "InstanceType": "t2.medium", "CreditSpecification": {"CpuCredits": "unlimited"}}'`

Comment: Try the `describe-launch-templates` and then `describe-launch-template-versions` AWS CLI commands. Links: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-launch-templates.html, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-launch-template-versions.html. CPU Credits should be shown in the response of the `describe-launch-template-versions` command.

Comment: Hey! I ended up just actually creating a JSON file to pass into the `create-launch-template` command and everything worked fine! Thanks for the help man