# I can't create a template with the output of get-launch-template-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am starting to play with AWS.
I have created an EC2 instance using the AWS management console.
I would like to be able to create new, similar instances using the CLI so I've been looking at get-launch-template-data (which states "Retrieves the configuration data of the specified instance. You can use this data to create a launch template.") and expected the output of that to be valid input to create-launch-template.

I've viewed the AWS CLI documentation, and looked on StackOverflow but the only related issues I've found has been these ones:
[Unable to create launchtemplate using awscli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890878/unable-to-create-launchtemplate-using-awscli) and 
[Amazon Launch Template - Updated AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102698/amazon-launch-template-updated-ami)

I've been running:

```
aws ec2 get-launch-template-data --instance-id "i-xxx" --query "LaunchTemplateData"  > MyLaunchData
aws ec2 create-launch-template --launch-template-name xxx --launch-template-data file://MyLaunchData
```

The error I get is:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInterfaceType.Malformed) when calling the CreateLaunchTemplate operation: '%s' is not a valid value for interface type. Enter a valid value and try again.
```

What I think is the relevant part of MyLaunchData is:

```
    "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
            "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
            "Description": "",
            "DeviceIndex": 0,
            "Groups": [
                "sg-xxx"
            ],
            "InterfaceType": "interface",
            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                {
                    "Primary": true,
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "xxx"
                }
            ],
            "SubnetId": "subnet-xxx"
        }
    ],
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?
(I've obviously replaced what I think is my data with xxx for privacy)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The InterfaceType is not allowed:

> '%s' is not a valid value for interface type

I know that you are using the output from *get-launch-template-data* but there is no *"InterfaceType": "interface"*.

[AWS EC2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html#cfn-ec2-networkinterface-interfacetype)

```
InterfaceType

Indicates the type of network interface. To create an Elastic Fabric Adapter (EFA),
specify efa. For more information, see Elastic Fabric Adapter in the Amazon Elastic
Compute Cloud User Guide.

Required: No

Type: String

Allowed Values: efa
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to vo1umen's answer, to get around this issue you obviously need to remove InterfaceType from the NetworkInterfaces array. One way of doing this is to use jq:

`jq -c 'del(.NetworkInterfaces[0]["InterfaceType"])' <<< $TemplateData`

The `-c` is to keep the JSON flat formatted, you may not need to do that when storing in a file.